# How to check if a div overlaps with another div every second?

Tags: javascript, foreach, collision, event-listener, overlapping

I am making a quick game about moving the player to dodge bullets, but I am having problems with how to detect if any bullet colided with the player. In game engines there would usually just exist eventlisteners for coliding of two objects, since I haven't found anything like that for webb development, I thought I could just use an infinite loop to check each bullet if it has collided with the player.

I can't do a `while (true)` loop, because it just crashes. I tried to make an interval in the spawn function of each bullets, but I couldn't figure out how to clear the interval after the bullet despawns. And I have also tried to just make an interval that would loop through existing bullets at the moment and check if the bullet is coliding, but for some reason I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: bullets.forEach is not a function` here is the code:

```
function checkOverlap(){
    let bullets = document.getElementsByClassName("bullet");
    if (bullets.length > 0){
        bullets.forEach(bullet => {
            let overlap = !(bullet.right < player.left || 
                    bullet.left > player.right || 
                    bullet.bottom < player.top || 
                    bullet.top > player.bottom)
            if (overlap){
                console.log("overlap");
            }
        });
    }
}
setInterval(checkOverlap, 1000);
```

I also wonder if this is even posible to detect the overlapping this way. Since I am using `transition` and `left, top, right, down` css properties to move my bullets, would it detect or do I need to use something else?

Comment: You flagged [collision](https://www.google.com/search?q=collision+detection+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which doesn't have a `forEach` method (and is a live reference to the DOM). Try `querySelectorAll('.bullet')` instead for a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access `forEach` because `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an `Array` - it returns a `NodeList` which behaves somewhat like an `Array`, but deviates in other ways - for one thing its prototype has no `forEach` method.

You can easily convert to an `Array` by doing the following instead:

```
let bullets = [ ...document.getElementsByClassName('bullet') ];
```

As far as collision goes, I recommend you use `getBoundingClientRect` (I often confused its spelling for `getClientBoundingRect`, now I remind myself that `B` preceeds `C` :D). This returns the absolute geometry of an html element, taking everything into account:

```js
let doCollide = (player, bullet) => {
  let playerBound = player.getBoundingClientRect();
  let bulletBound = bullet.getBoundingClientRect();

  // (px, py) and (bx, by) represent the center of the player and bullet
  let px = playerBound.left + playerBound.width * 0.5;
  let py = playerBound.top + playerBound.height * 0.5;
  let bx = bulletBound.left + bulletBound.width * 0.5;
  let by = bulletBound.top + bulletBound.height * 0.5;

  let wOff = (playerBound.width + bulletBound.width) * 0.5;
  let hOff = (playerBound.height + bulletBound.height) * 0.5;

  // Collision occurs when bullet and player are separated on neither x nor y axes
  return Math.abs(px - bx) < wOff && Math.abs(py - by) < hOff;
}

let player = document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0];
let bullet = document.getElementsByClassName('bullet')[0];

let testFn = () => {

  player.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)}px`;
  player.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)}px`;
  bullet.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)}px`;
  bullet.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)}px`;
  
  if (doCollide(player, bullet)) {
    player.classList.add('coll');
    bullet.classList.add('coll');
  } else {
    player.classList.remove('coll');
    bullet.classList.remove('coll');
  }
  
};

setInterval(testFn, 1500);
testFn();
```

```css
html, body { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.player, .bullet { position: absolute; }
.player { width: 150px; height: 150px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 150, 0, 1); }
.bullet { width: 60px; height: 90px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 210, 0, 1); }

.player.coll { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(200, 0, 0, 1); }
.bullet.coll { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); }
```

```html
<div class="player"></div>
<div class="bullet"></div>
```